# why do we need to create localrc file for openstack

Tags: installation, openstack

why do we need to create localrc file for openstack installation when package has stackrc, openrc config files present already? No need to say i am a newbie in OpenStack. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the localrc file is used to customize the OpenStack installation. Suppose you want to install additional services like tacker, designate etc and also to define the endpoints ur and many other customizable configurations.

Comment: If I do not provide localrc to my devstack....We will still be able to configure the services at run time? Just curious

Comment: I have never tried installing OpenStack without localrc. We cannot configure services at run time, we need to unstack it, reconfigure it, again stack it.

Comment: @abhilash- Thanks, it helped!